# sql query error - logical or syntax

Tags: php, sql

At the moment I am running an update query which is working, however it allows null values to be inserted which I don't want.

```
mysql_query('UPDATE community_table SET 
age = "'.$age.'", 
gender = "'.$gender.'", 
pregnant = "'.$pregnant.'", 
diet = "'.$diet.'",
smoker = "'.$smoker.'",
alcohol = "'.$alcohol.'",
exercise = "'.$exercise.'",
bmi = "'.$bmi.'",
sleeping = "'.$sleeping.'",
stress = "'.$stress.'", 
education = "'.$education.'"
WHERE username = "' . $_SESSION['user'] . '" ');
```

I tried this query which seems to prevent null values being entered, however it also prevents values being entered when the variables are not null.

```
age = "'.$age.'", 
gender = "'.$gender.'", 
pregnant = "'.$pregnant.'", 
diet = "'.$diet.'",
smoker = "'.$smoker.'",
alcohol = "'.$alcohol.'",
exercise = "'.$exercise.'",
bmi = "'.$bmi.'",
sleeping = "'.$sleeping.'",
stress = "'.$stress.'", 
education = "'.$education.'"

WHERE age IS NOT NULL,
gender     IS NOT NULL,
pregnant   IS NOT NULL,
diet       IS NOT NULL,
smoker     IS NOT NULL, 
alcohol    IS NOT NULL,
exercise   IS NOT NULL,
bmi        IS NOT NULL,
sleeping   IS NOT NULL,
stress     IS NOT NULL,
education  IS NOT NULL and where
username = "' . $_SESSION['user'] . '" ');
```

Is there something wrong with the above query, or do I perhaps have a null value in my input?

Thanks.

Comment: in which column your query insert null value ?

Comment: Any column that I do not assign a new value for. Basically any previous values are being turned into null values unless I reassign a value to them. They are not retaining their previous values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent empty string from being sent from your script or try this

```
UPDATE community_table SET
    education = IFNULL($education, education) -- if null, maintain previous value
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working. I placed a "," at the end of each line before the next test. Was that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just check values before insert like this -

```
UPDATE community_table SET
    education = ifnull($education, education)
```